Automate macros in excel using python
I want to automate adding a macro in Excel files using a python code written in Visual Studio
How should I do that?
What should be the code like
import win32com.client

def add_macro_to_excel(excel_file_path, macro_name, macro_code):
    # Initialize Excel application object
    excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

    try:
        # Open Excel workbook
        workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(excel_file_path)

        # Access VBA project
        vba_project = workbook.VBProject

        # Add a new standard module (vbext_ct_StdModule)
        new_module = vba_project.VBComponents.Add(1)

        # Add VBA code to the module
        new_module.CodeModule.AddFromString(f"Sub {macro_name}()\n{macro_code}\nEnd Sub")

        # Save and close workbook
        workbook.Save()
        workbook.Close()

        print(f"Macro '{macro_name}' added to '{excel_file_path}'")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    finally:
        # Quit Excel application
        excel_app.Quit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
     # Specify the path to your Excel file
     file_path = r"file path "

     # Specify the name and code of the macro to add
     macro_name = "CDM"
     macro_code = """
     *MACRO CODE*
     """

    # Add the macro to the Excel file
    add_macro_to_excel(file_path, macro_name, macro_code)


I expected the code would be visible in excel also but it is not

Why not have a template excel file with the macro already included?

then I'll need to add the macros to the new file again when I'll work on updated files so in order to avoid repetitive task, I was looking for this option
